# Angular 1.5 + jquery scroll animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation

I have small angular SPA with couple routes. What I wanted is to have fadein effect only on #/welcome/ page. My jquery works ok but the problem is - its running on all pages and in another pages elements what should be animated just doesnt exist and thats the reason I have errors on my console when user scroll... I tried run script only when route changed and than check if location is /#/welcome but it always running even if not... I tried to put code only to controller which should scoped it to section with animating elements but it also run in another pages... Im confused please help

```
      $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
            if (window.location.hash == '#/welcome') {
                function check(element , fadeEffect ) {
                    $(window).on('scroll' , function(){
                        var position = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight()  ;
                        var elem = $(element).offset().top + ($(element).innerHeight()) / 2;
                        if (elem <= position) {
                            $(element).addClass(fadeEffect);
                        }
                        else {
                            $(element).removeClass(fadeEffect);
                        }
                    });
                }
                check('.tablet' , 'fadeInRight');
                check('.padding' , 'fadeInLeft');
            }
            else {
                console.log('another page');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is SPA, so once you add event to window it will keep until you close the browser tab.
You have to remove the event on destroying welcome page, so remove all those codes and add these to your welcome page controller:

```
//in welcome page controller

var onScroll = function(){
    var queries = [
        {elm: '.tablet', effect: 'fadeInRight'},
        {elm: '.padding', effect: 'fadeInLeft'}
    ];

    for (var i=0, j=queries.length; i<j; i++) {
        var position = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight()  ;
        var elem = $(queries[i].elm).offset().top + ($(queries[i].elm).innerHeight()) / 2;
        if (elem <= position) {
            $(queries[i].elm).addClass(queries[i].effect);
        }
        else {
            $(queries[i].elm).removeClass(queries[i].effect);
        }
    }
}

$(window).on('scroll' , onScroll);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $(window).off('scroll' , onScroll);
});
```